# ¿como lleno un select para editar los datos?

Tags: php, mysql

Bunas tardes con todos, tengo un formulario en el que lleva un slect y en el cual al editar el registro deseo que me capture el valor y no me muetres como vacio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que uso para llenar el select

```
                <select id="tab_provincia_id_provincia">
                    <option value="0">Seleccione:</option>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($data1 as $dat1) {

                        echo '<option value="'.$dat1[id_provincia].'" selected>'.$dat1[nombre].'</option>';

                    
                    }
                    
                    ?>
                </select>
```

Comment: Intenta llenarlo de la siguiente manera: `echo '<option value="'.$dat1["id_provincia"].'">'.$dat1["nombre"].'</option>';`

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta @CesarRomero pero ya lo intente pero al momento de llamar al formulario de edicion de datos no me captura el dato del select y me deja en blnaco

Comment: Podrías explicar mejor te deja en blanco todas las opciones del select? o cuando dices que no te captura el dato del select es al momento de guardar?

Comment: al llamar un formulario para agregar un nuevo registro si funciona el select, es decir captura los datos que llamo de mi base, el problema que tengo es que al momento de editar ese registro en el select no trae el dato a editar como se muetra en los imput sino que muestra vacio

Comment: Que raro la funcion por defecto de un elemento select es mostrar de primero el valor seleccionado una vez que el usuario hace click sobre un elemento de la lista

Comment: Remueve el 'selected' eso no ayuda a que se muestre

Comment: Si no esta imprimiendo el dato, es mas seguro que no esta recibiendo el dato haz un print_r $data1

Comment: @AugustoM ya le retire el 'selected' y tampoco me funciono, de igual manera le realice el print_r para revisar si captura el dato a editar y si lo hace, pero el problema es que no me muestra en el formulario y al momento de actualizar la información me envia como null

Comment: Para comenzar tienes una falla en tu form de HTML, para que un elemento seleccionado de tu lista se envie en el POST tienes que agregar el atributo name a tu select, te quedaria algo asi -> <select id="tab_provincia_id_provincia" name="provincia"> por ejemplo

Comment: Pon el print_r de tu array, por lo menos unos 3 registros para ver que estas enviando a imprimir

Answer (score 0):

lo que sucede esque no logro llenar el select al llamar un formulario de edición; el dato se esta caputarndo pero no se imprime en el comobox select
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Faltan varias cosas ahi para que hagas un debug, comienza por en la misma pagina mandar a imprimir tu array, a ver si lo estas recibiendo de tu query, eso de la consola no se entiende que es, luego al menos a mi PHP me mandaria un error de offset (valor no encontrado) de un array por poner incorrecto el key del campo del array, no es mismos $miarray["dato"] que $miarray[dato]

Comment: el array se muestra en el select, lo que no me muetra es el valor que tiene el registro al momento de llamar al formulario de editar, muestra solo un campo en blanco pero al desplegar el select se encuentran todos los datos del array, y si quiero guardar la edicion del registro debo volver a escoger la opcion del select